# Need sth like "def groupByKeyWithRDD(partitioner: Partitioner): RDD[(K, RDD[V])] = ???"

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

In our use case of using the groupByKey(...): RDD[(K, Iterable[V]], there might be a case that even for a single key (an extreme case though), the associated Iterable[V] could resulting in OOM.

Is it possible to provide the above 'groupByKeyWithRDD'?

And, ideally, it would be great if the internal impl of the RDD[V] is smart enough to only spill the data into disk upon a configured threshold. That way, we won't sacrifice the performance for the normal cases as well.

Any suggestions/comments are welcomed. Thanks a lot!

Just a side note: we do understand the points mentioned here: https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html, and the 'reduceByKey', 'foldByKey' don't quite fit our needs right now, that is to say, we couldn't really avoid 'groupByKey'.

Comment: I don't quite get your question!

Comment: Unfortunately, nested RDD's are not possible. The last post on [this thread](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Rdd-of-Rdds-td17025.html) does a good job of explaining why. I think there isn't a way that I can think of to remedy your situation (or in general, for running `*ByKey` operations with heavy key skew). If you can find some way to logically distribute keys more evenly, that would obviously help.

Comment: Usually, what I do is associating the two RDDs with a similar "key" and then perform a join action on that key. Which is a very expensive operation, but it's still a good workaround.

Comment: @RohanAletty thanks for your comment. It's not necessarily to be a nested RDD, RDD[(K, Stream[V])] would also be ok, as long as the values are lazy collections.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the #(of-unique-keys) << #(key-value-pairs), which seems to be the case, there should be no need for `RDD[(K, RDD[V])]`. Instead you can transform into `Map[(K, RDD[V])]` by mapping unique keys with filter:

```scala
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

def splitByKey[K : ClassTag, V: ClassTag](rdd: RDD[(K, V)]): Map[K, RDD[V]] = {
  val keys = rdd.keys.distinct.collect.toSeq
  keys.map(key => (key -> rdd.filter{case (k, _) => k == key}.values)).toMap
}
```

It requires multiple scans over data so it is not exactly cheap but doesn't require shuffling, gives you much better control over caching and is rather unlikely to cause OOM as long as initial RDD fits into memory.